# React- How do I add react icons to input field that change depending on Formik / Yup validation?

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, formik, yup

I am new to React, and I'm trying to get specific icons to show up at end of the input field depending on the Formik / Yup validation.
So if my validation fails I want a red cross icon to show up at the end of the field and a tick icon if the validation is successful. The icons should only show up once the validation kicks in.

[Something similar to this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBGJS.png)

This is my current Login Form component:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const LoginForm = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
    onSubmit={(values) => {
      console.log(values);
    }}
    validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
      email: Yup.string().email().required(),
      password: Yup.string().required(),
    })}
  >
    {(props) => {
      const { errors, touched, isSubmitting } = props;
      return (
        <Form >
          <label htmlFor="email"></label>
          <Field
            type="text"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
            className={errors.email && touched.email && "errors"}
          />
          {errors.email && touched.email && (
            <div className="errorFeedback">The email is incorrect.</div>
          )}
          <Field
            type="password"
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            className={errors.password && touched.password && "errors"}
          />
          {errors.password && touched.password && (
            <div className="errorFeedback">The password is incorrect.</div>
          )}
          <button type="submit" >
            Sign In
           </button>
        </Form>
      );
    }}
  </Formik>
);
```

I assume it has to do with material UI textfield and Inputprops to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I fixed this issue with the Material UI library. My steps

1. I made my Formik {Field} Module into the Material UI {Textfield} Module to be able to add the icons using the InputProps={}. This also required readding the {handleChange, handleBlur} props as validation didn't kick in on the fields otherwise.
2. I used endAdorment property to add the icons to the field and added conditions directly inside it to display the correct icon based on the Formik validation.

My code after all the changes, I haven't checked it with an API call validation, but I assume it works similarly with it.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { TextField, InputAdornment } from "@material-ui/core";
import CheckCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle";
import CancelIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Cancel";

const LoginForm = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
    onSubmit={(values) => {
      console.log(values);
    }}
    validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
      email: Yup.string().email().required(),
      password: Yup.string().required().min(8),
    })}
  >
    {(props) => {
      const { errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur } = props;
      return (
        <Form >
          <Field
            variant="outlined"
            component={TextField}
            type="text"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            id="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
            size="small"
            error={errors.email && touched.email && true}
            // Mui icons based on Validation
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end" style={{ outline: "none" }}>
                  {errors.email && touched.email && (
                    <CancelIcon
                      style={{ color: "red" }}
                      fontSize="default"
                    ></CancelIcon>
                  )}
                  {!errors.email && touched.email && (
                    <CheckCircleIcon
                      style={{ color: "#05cc30" }}
                      fontSize="default"
                    ></CheckCircleIcon>
                  )}
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
          />
          <Field
            variant="outlined"
            component={TextField}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            type="password"
            id="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            size="small"
            error={errors.password && touched.password && true}
            // Mui icons based on Validation
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end" style={{ outline: "none" }}>
                  {errors.password && touched.password && (
                    <CancelIcon
                      style={{ color: "red" }}
                      fontSize="default"
                    ></CancelIcon>
                  )}
                  {!errors.password && touched.password && (
                    <CheckCircleIcon
                      style={{ color: "#05cc30" }}
                      fontSize="default"
                    ></CheckCircleIcon>
                  )}
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
          />
          // Add your button
        </Form>
      );
    }}
  </Formik>
);
```

Since I couldn't find a direct answer to this exact issue and a similar question about this exact issue asked 9 months back is also not answered, I have posted a simple solution I implemented. Hopefully it's helpful.